# jquery click simple modal plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, modal-dialog

i would like to pass a variable into my javascript, using simple modal plugin, http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/,  .click function in my view (html) ... how this is my javascript:

> 

```
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    var src = "http://365.ericmmartin.com/"
    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
        closeHTML:"",
        containerCss:{
        backgroundColor:"#fff",
        borderColor:"#fff",
        height:450,
        padding:0,
        width:830
        },
        overlayClose:true
    });
        return false;
    });
```

and here is what i tried in my html:

> `%a.basic{:href => "#", :onclick => 'var src = "http://somesite.com/"'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $(this).attr("friendid") makes it work:

```
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
$.modal('<iframe src="' + $(this).attr("friendid") + '" height="474" width="532" style="border:0;" scrolling="no">', {
    closeHTML:"",
    containerCss:{

    },
    overlayClose:true
});
    return false;
```

And in the HTML create an attribute called "friendid" or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) has this exact functionality already built for you. I would highly recommend you try out this approach:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/